# Can I use one physical disk in two mdadm arrays?

Tags: lvm, raid, mdadm

I have three disks that I'd like to use in a RAID setup;

- 2x4 TB
- 1x8 TB

Can I create two partitions on the 8 TB disk and include in two RAID 1 arrays with the 4 TB disks?

```
RAID 1 array 1: 4 TB physical disk 1 + 4 TB partition on 8 TB disk
RAID 1 array 2: 4 TB physical disk 2 + 4 TB partition on 8 TB disk
```

Are there any downsides to this? Apart from the fact that loosing the 8 TB drive would degrade both arrays of course.

Combining these two arrays with LVM would give me one volume with 8 TB usable space, or so I hope.

I am migrating away from a Synology NAS with SHR (Synology Hydrid Raid), and I think they do something like this to be able to include disks of unequal size in the volume.

Comment: Seems sensible to be. You could also combine the two 4TB to make an 8TB, then raid them together. (Note that loosing the 8TB will not degrade it will kill the device. raid 0 has no redundancy and will create a 16TB device that is faster than a non-raid.)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, Oh; I meant RAID 1, not 0... Sorry, edited the question with the correct RAID type :) Is combining the two 4 TB drives still an option if redundancy is required?

Comment: Performance won't be as good since more IO will be going to the 8 TB drive and it will struggle to keep up with the two 4 TB drives.

Comment: Yes make the 2 smaller drive into a bigger one, then raid the big with new drive made of the two smaller ones. And as @psusi says the performance [for write] will be that of the slower drive.

Comment: So make a LVM volume with the two smaller drives, and use that in the RAID config together with the 8 TB drive?

Comment: No; make a raid0 of the two smaller drives, then a raid1 of that raid0 and the larger drive.

Comment: @psusi Great thanks, I'll give that a try :)